# Вызов разного Dialogbox при помощи jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Имеется код из примера jQuery https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated. Хочу понять, как правильно вызывать только тот `Dialog`, к которому принадлежит кнопка.

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1
      }
    });
 
    $( ".opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<button class="opener">Open Dialog</button>

<div class="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
 
<button class="opener">Open Dialog</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".opener" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( ".dialog" ).eq($(".opener").index(this)).dialog( "open" );
});
```